# JSON-RPC and handle to current document

Tags: xpages, datasource, rpc

Good day folks!

I have a call (CSJS) to a JSON-RPC service in my XPage to get the value of a viewScope variable. I use this call to cycle through my field names (dynamically) and validate them.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get a handle to the datasource (document1 in my case) to which these fields are bound, from the RPC service.

Here's the call:

```
// Use the JSON-RPC Service to get the number of asset item rows 
// from the viewScope variable
var deferred = myRPCService.getScopeVar();
deferred.addCallback(function(result){

alert(result); // <-- viewScope variable value

// get the dynamic field names for the asset items based on row #
var itemname = '';    
for (var i = 1; i < result; i++) {
var itemname = 'replace'+(i < 10? '0':'')+ i
if (document1.getItemValueString(itemname) == ""){
    // do this
} else{
    // do that
}    
}
});
```

I do get back the value of the viewScope variable from the RPC call but I can't get beyond that. Any pointers/examples would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Dan

PS: See my comment below ...

Comment: Addendum: I suppose I could circumvent the problem by assigning the response (result) from the JSON-RPC call to a CSJS variable and then I can continue my processing outside of the callback function. However, there is the little matter of timing. 

// Use the JSON-RPC Service to get the viewScope variable value
var deferred = myRPCService.getScopeVar();
var rowCount = "";
deferred.addCallback(function(result){
rowCount = result;
alert("CT1 = " + rowCount);
});
alert("CT2 = " + rowCount);

the second alert CT2 fires before the first with an empty value and then CT1 fires with the count. Sigh!

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what calls the JSON-RPC event, so I will guess and say it is a button. You will have to have an *additional* serverside event set the viewScope variable to the value of `document1.getItemValueString(itemname)` which you can then retrieve in the RPC.

Your SSJS event code will look something like:

```
viewScope.result = document1.getItemValueString(itemname);
```

The additional event can be onmouseover *(not recommended)* or onkeypress.  I assume you are using onclick clientside for this code, you can't use the onclick serverside because this code would need to run prior to your clientside. You will want the viewScope to contain fresh data, hence this suggestion. If the data doesn't need to be fresh, then set it on page load.

---

Another idea would be to call two RPC's.  The first one can set the viewScope variable and the second can use it.  The first one won't need a callback, and just calls a java or SSJS function that sets the viewScope. Personally I like this better than my first suggestion.

Comment: Steve, to answer your question the RPC call is being made from a button. And to clarify, I'm 'getting' not setting the value of the viewScope variable. That is not a problem. As you can see from my code, I have an alert that returns the value in the callback function. However, I don't know how/can't seem to get a handle to the datasource (document1) from within the callback function.

Comment: No, you get the value of the datasource field in your scoped variable, not a handle to document1. You can call me if you want, my phone # is on facebook.  Will be available for next 30 min (until 6:30 central)